# SQLite GROUP BY

Tags: sqlite

I am using DB Browser for SQLite to extract some interesting data from my database but I encountered one big problem with `GROUP BY` statement.
Even the most basic `SELECT` I can imagine is not working properly.

(Filename nvarchar(2147483647))

`SELECT FileName FROM TableName WHERE FileName LIKE '%Nieminen%' GROUP BY FileName` gives 5 rows even though I know that there are 9 distinct FileNames containing the phrase 'Nieminen' (I've browsed it).

Can it be possible that `GROUP BY` in sqlite compares only N (e.g. 10) initial characters? From my observation it might be true...

Any clues?

Comment: Yep, that's a mystery. What does `SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT(FileName)) FROM TableName WHERE FileName LIKE '%Nieminen%';` return?

Comment: "AustralianOpen 2012 MS158 J.Nieminen-D.Nalbandian.txt"
"FrenchOpen 2011 MS133 D.Ferrer-J.Nieminen.txt"
"MiamiAtp 2014 MS211 A.Dolgopolov-J.Nieminen.txt"
"UsOpen 2011 MS128 J.Nieminen-F.Verdasco.txt"


It seems to group by 'Australian', 'French', 'Miami', 'USOpen'. The problem is that there were at least two Australian Opens (in this db) in which Nieminen played.

Comment: Sorry I didn't read your comment carefully, of course 4. The above is full result of the initial SELECT statement.

Comment: Your question would be easier to investigate if you provided a sample data set that reproduces the issue. Try to strip it down as much as you can - eliminate as many columns and rows as you can without making the strange behaviour go away.

Comment: If the `SELECT` I specified returns 4, I would expect your original query to return 4 rows as well... are there some spelling mistakes in your data? Also, don't forget that the match is case sensitive, so 'Nieminen' is not the same as 'nieminen'.

Comment: It looks a little bit chaotic but that was a typo in my post- I should have written "4 rows" instead of 5. Case sensitivity- thanks for the reminder but in this case surnames are always written in that way.
Mark Amery- thanks for your remark I started from the very basic dataset, containing only 1 column related only to that player and it returns 9 rows, as expected. Now I have to work on it.

Comment: Could >250k rows be the problem for SQLite? I just cut the table of 20 other columns (some of them TEXT) and everything seems to work just fine...

Comment: There is no limit on the length of compared values or on the number of rows.

Comment: Maybe the name of a column- "Context" was an ambiguity with some name from sqlite.

Answer (score -1):

why don't you try out the following:

```
SELECT DISTINCT FileName FROM TableName WHERE FileName LIKE '%Nieminen%'
```

Comment: It returns just the same result as for GROUP BY (see the first reply to the bsa's post)

Comment: if it does, then there's nothing wrong with the query. The other options must simply come from other places, but trust me, the "distinct" option shows you all distinct values that match your condition